# Save/Load a game in MVVM via Binary Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, mvvm

I'm working on a text-based game in WPF using the MVVM pattern. I would like to use Binary Serialization to save and load the game as I did when I was using WinForms, but with this pattern I don't know how to do this properly. Which classes need to be serialized to preserve the necessary data? Is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

EDIT: If you're going to downvote the question at least explain why.

Comment: -1 `Which classes need to be serialized to preserve the necessary data` depends on your code. *you* should know which data is necessary.

Comment: I didn't know if there was a sort of convention in MVVM. Sorry for asking and trying to learn how to do things properly.

Comment: as i4v said; any data which needs to persist must be serialised. From a brief look at MVVM, If the View and ViewModel are driven by the Model, then the Model is the only thing which _should_ need to be serialised. If the ViewModel is not entirely driven by the model, then you'll need to serialise parts of that. It depends entirely on your implementation of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which classes need to be serialized to preserve the necessary data?

This might sound circular, but: whatever you need preserved. Sometimes this can be your domain model - the M in MVVM. If this isn't immediately obvious from you model, then I would say: add a new DTO layer. This DTO model would be simply: what you want stored. Then you can save and load without affecting the rest of the system. Obviously you need some code to map to/from the DTO model and whatever model you are using.

> Is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

If, by "binary serialization" you mean `BinaryFormatter`, then be very very careful - it can be brittle as you version your app. There are other serializers that read/write in a binary- (rather than text) based format, but which are less … *fussy* than `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you don't mind me asking, what are some of those other serializers?

Comment: @Dennis I'm partial to protobuf (and protobuf-net in particular) - but I'm biased as a library author. Thrift, msgpack, ice - are a few more.